# How to get relation 'table1' OR 'table2' OR 'table3' into one table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm a newbie here and also in Laravel, so please excuse me. I have a table named 'products' and this table related to the 'recipes' table via many-to-one relation(One of the recipes has a lot of products). -'recipes' table keeps reference code- Here's where I stuck; the 'recipes' table has one-to-one relations to three different tables that keeping the "real" product recipes. Those tables have different recipe contents like,

Alkaline table;

```
   Schema::create('alkalines', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('recipe_id');
        $table->integer('sodium_bicarbonate');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Acets table;

```
   Schema::create('acets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('recipe_id');
        $table->integer('sodium_chloride');
        $table->integer('acetic_acid');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I'm able to fetch all relations if I start with one of these(e.g with Acet model). **But** if, I list all of products and try to fetch it's recipe, I have to use a bunch of 'if and else's. Just can't get the recipe like;

```
$product->recipe-> "one of the three recipe tables' content"
```

And my 'recipes' table:

```
Schema::create('recipes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('ref');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I believe it's easy, just missing something. Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think
You can get every relation individual them merge the arrays
like

```
$arr1=Alkalines::with('recipe')->get()->toArray();
$arr2==Acets::with('recipe')->get()->toArray();
$arr3=***************************;
```

```
array_merge($arr1,$arr2,$arr3)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. It makes sense but, it gives an error. All I want is a variable that keeps data from all of three tables. Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: Something like; collections can't be assigned to an array. When I try to return
`return array_merge($arr1,$arr2,$arr3)`

Comment: add ->toArray() after get();

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

If you have relations set up properly, you can use 'collection->pluck()' to retrieve their results, no matter how deeply nested in different relations.

Example:

`$game->players->stats` won't work, because `players` is a collection that doesn't have a `stats` attribute, method or field.

So, what you can do is use pluck() and collapse() to retrieve result of relations:

`$game->players->pluck('stats')->collapse()`

Comment: Thank you for your time. It gives an error when I implement your code like this: 
$recipe->pluck('sodium_bicarbonate')->collapse()
The error is:
 "Undefined property: stdClass::$sodium_bicarbonate. I think the 'hasOne' relation returns an array instead of a collection. What can I do?

Comment: If you aren't fetching a nested relation, try `$recipe->sodium_bicarbonate` instead, without `collapse()` or `pluck()` because pluck() requires a collection.

Answer (score 0):

I edit the code from @mohamedhassan a little bit, and it worked!

```
public function solutionMerge()
{
    $arr1=Alkaline::with('recipe')->get();
    $arr2=Acet::with('recipe')->get();
    $arr3=Glucose::with('recipe')->get();

    $solutionMerge = collect([$arr1,$arr2,$arr3]);

    return $solutionMerge;
}
```

Just assigned arrays into a collection. And then use `collapse()`. 
And now, I'm able to fetch data like `$solutionMerge->recipe->id` 
Thank you people, for your precious time and immense knowledge!